# Is it a bad thing that txid_exhaustion_oldest_txid_num is constantly increasing?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

We recently setup netdata to monitor a self-hosted PostgreSQL server.

**Is it a bad thing that txid_exhaustion_oldest_txid_num is constantly increasing?**

[image]

**What we did**

- PostgreSQL is running in v13
- We've run a full-vacuum (`vacuumdb --full --all --jobs=1 --verbose --analyze --username=XXXX --password`) on all logical databases and only got these errors:

  ERROR: relation "pg_temp_31.temp_lig_plo"
  ERROR: relation "pg_temp_31.lst_lig_plo"
- We've dropped the schema "pg_temp_31" but still had a similar issue.
- `max_prepared_transactions` is 0
- `SELECT * FROM pg_prepared_xacts` is empty on all databases
- We've restarted the DB (so all idle transactions were disconnected) and still observe this increase

Comment: Can you please describe how "txid_exhaustion_oldest_txid_num" is measured?

Comment: Offtopic: Version 11 is EOL since November 2023. You'd better upgrade to a newer version

Comment: @FrankHeikens sorry my bad, it's PG 13 and we cannot upgrade (if only...) because a proprietary software depends on it and does not support past PG 13 for now

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe netdata is based on prometheus postgresql exporter. We've found the SQL query for this metric here: https://github.com/prometheus-community/postgres_exporter/blob/master/collector/pg_database_wraparound.go#L41-L62

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, this graphic seems to be about transaction ID wraparound.

Check if any of your databases have a problem with that:

```
SELECT datname, age(datfrozenxid) AS xact_age
FROM pg_database
ORDER BY xact_age DESC;
```

If that number is not much above 200 million for all databases, you don't need to worry.  If the number is significantly higher, connect to that database and see which tables have a problem:

```
SELECT oid::regclass, age(relfrozenxid) AS xact_age
FROM pg_class
ORDER BY xact_age DESC;
```

If there are any numbers far above 200 million (or whatever else [`autovacuum_freeze_max_age`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-autovacuum.html#GUC-AUTOVACUUM-FREEZE-MAX-AGE) is set to), either autovacuum doesn't start on that table, or it is taking too long, or something is blocking its progress.

Try processing those tables manually with

```
VACUUM (VERBOSE) table_name;
```

The output should tell you what is going on and, if possible, fix the problem.

Comment: Finally a nice explanation about "how it should be", amazing, let me check that and come back at you!